# love open gyms..does it potentially mean to open gym?

Tags: word-usage, listening

Again I am sorry I am asking things about NPR's products. However, **after confirming the transcription**, I am afraid to say if someone could help me about **[this.](http://pd.npr.org/anon.npr-mp3/npr/atc/2016/04/20160422_atc_40-year-old_female_gymnast_qualifies_for_7th_olympics.mp3?orgId=1&topicId=1055&d=113&p=2&story=475311847&t=progseg&e=475231563&seg=3&siteplayer=true&dl=1)**

Around 1:20～

> ah I love ths sport of gymnastics. I actually just came from, my coach, Kelly 
>    hill's gym in Maryland, now just with my two daughters,  and **we love open gym**...

Is she ( Dominique Dawes ) saying she loves "to open" gym? or she love, literally speaking, open, which is, may be a gym outside where players excersize
outside...

Which one could be? correct?

Thank you.

Comment: “Open” is an adjective in that sentence. The gym isn't **(out) in the open**, it's (generally) free for anyone to come; it's just an open practice.

Comment: "Open Gym" usually means a period during which some or all of the gymnasium's facilities are made available for patrons to use on their own, outside formal classes.

Comment: So am I correct to imagine, for example, Had I heard today Michael Jordan would open his Charllote Hornet's basket court for anyone. Is this **open gym** such a sort of thing?

Comment: According to Stoney's, it looks like mine is completely wrong....I am really sorry for bothering you all.

Comment: So is user26844291's comment a correct one? During certain time, the gym will be "open" so that anyone can play or practice in the gym...? I am sorry.

Comment: StoneyB and user2684291 are essentially in agreement. The gym is freely available to patrons.  Open = unrestricted.  **Love** takes a to-infinitive complement: She loves to read.

Comment: Or considering the number of arrows, it is not actually "open", but actually "closed", as StoneyB says,  "are made available for patrons to **use on their own,**". I am sorry there seem to be 2 different ideas. Sorry for bothering again. I apologize.

Comment: **open** lacks such a universal precise definition. In one place it might mean "non-members can use if they pay a small one-time fee" in another it could mean "open to the public at no charge".  *In some manner* the rules have been relaxed, made less restrictive.  Or it could be that members can use the equipment in whatever way they please, in whatever order, because there is no instruction scheduled at that time.  Compare "open swim".

Comment: This is my quess though, may be you might think I am a racist, Dominique is AA, didn't she just forget to say love **opening** a gym??? When I listen to the radio, if you follow the context carefully, here she is saying she ( won ) a gold meal in Olympics because she was in love with her coach Kelly Hill, and now they got married so that they "would like to" open gym.......although this is my guess though?

Comment: No. Your guess is wrong.  "We love open gym" when spoken by a native speaker does not mean "we would love to open a gym."

Comment: No need for apologies, but you should have your keyboard checked. It looks as though the question-mark key may be sticky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only three verbs omit *to* when an infinitive follows.  *Love* is not one of them.

The following is an excerpt from [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/infinitives-with-and-without-to):

- We use the infinitive without to after modal verbs can, could, may, might, will, shall, would, should, must:
- We also use the infinitive without to after *let*, *make* and (optionally) *help*:

> He lets us use some of his land to grow vegetables.
>
> You can’t make a cat do anything it doesn’t want to do.
>
> I just want to help you (to) understand the situation better.

So this means in *we love open gym*, *open* has to be a modifier.

And as the comments say, *open* can mean "temporarily available to anyone or the public at large" - a common phrase is *open house* where a house seller will allow anyone to come into the house to look at it, not just those invited by the seller.  Many gyms are only available to those who are a member, but an *open gym* can mean anyone may workout - you might still have to pay a fee, but you don't have to buy a yearly membership.

Comment: Could you please, if you have time, explaine **why** you think she is inserting the sentence in the question "we love open gym"...does it suggest she does no longer want to practice like a proessional like an Olympian in a closed gym? May be?

Comment: @KentaroTomono Regardless of how the gym operates financially, 'open gym' is a time when users direct their own activities rather than working under the direction of a teacher. That's why Dawes **and her daughters** love open gym: because (as she goes on to say) "it's about **play**", not about working toward some achievement.

Comment: There could be more verbs such as have, hear, see, watch, etc. Saying only three verbs omit to is a little misleading.